# How to execute a long CURL command on zsh on mac terminal?

Tags: macos, curl, command-line, terminal, zsh

Trying to run a curl command on macos terminal which I was able to run from a windows command prompt. The curl command is relatively long with multiple "--data-urlencode" flags (5 total) and then the final -v  flag. On windows, I can simply copy/paste the command to the command prompt or powershell, press Enter, and it runs fine. However, on macos terminal using zsh, the command prompt just shows a reverse prompt after I try to press Enter. It's as if it is waiting for more input or some other run command which I am not aware of.

On macos, I have been able to run shorter curl commands without any issues, but when I paste in a relatively longer curl command, I am presented with more prompts as if zsh doesn't realize the command input is done. I have also tried to manually type out the command to see if copy/paste is the issue, but same problem. I have also tried to change the order of the flag options, but that doesn't make any difference either. I have googled the heck out of this, but alas - no joy.

Comment: The command you're pasting apparently contains some shell metacharacter(s) that're being interpreted differently by zsh than by PowerShell. This is not surprising,  since zsh (and other unix shells) and PowerShell have significantly different syntax. But without knowing the specifics, it's impossible to say exactly what's happening, or how to translate the command to unix shell syntax.

Comment: Thanks for taking a moment to reply. The command doesn't seem to have anything that I would consider windows-specific. Just as follows:

`> curl --data-urlencode "param_1=value_1" --data-urlencode "param_2=value_2" --data-urlencode "param_n=value_n" -v https://somesite.com/blah/blah
<
<
<`


As shown above, I just use several --data-urlencode flag options and end with -v for verbose and then the URL to access; nothing fancy. But after pressing Enter, the prompt just reverses position and looks like it's waiting for more input.

Thanks again.

Comment: But apparently there *is* something in there that's causing the problem. And as I said, without knowing the actual command, there's no way to tell what it is. Please provide an example of a command that actually shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
curl -v -w"%{http_code}\n" --stdout=/tmp/curl_out --stderr=/tmp/curl_err \
-u "user@password" 'https://yoursite.yourdomain.com/api/query' \
--data-urlencode 'param1=value 1' \
--data-urlencode 'param2=value 2' | jq .
```

Comment: Please [edit] and add an explanation why you think it will help to solve the original issue.